# Usar dois títulos (labels) em um input group bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Como posso usar dois tílos (label) em cima de um group button usando bootstrap?

imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é usar "range" numérico de 0 a 10, com um título na ponta esquerda e um título do lado direito.

Comment: Só colocar dois labels e uma `margin` no **label 1**.

Comment: Pode exemplificar com o código? porque o tamanho desse "group button" é variável

Comment: A resposta do Hugo já lhe atende não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opção 1

Usando o próprio *grid* do Bootstrap vc coloca o `btn-group` em um `row` e as `labels` em um `row` acima, cada `label` vc deixa de uma lado do `row` usando as classes  `flex` do Bootstrap

Essa opção não tem css customizado, apenas o css nativo do Bootstrap

```css
/* só com o css nativo do Bootstrap */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-between text-right">
        <label class="">
            label 1
        </label>
        <label class="">
            label 2
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="btn-group w-100 btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-secondary w-100 active">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-secondary w-100">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-secondary w-100">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

---

**Opção 2**

Usando um `before` e um `after` no `btn-group`, no `content` de cada *pseudo elemento* vc coloca o texto que quiser e deixa um alinhado a direita e outro a esquerda.

```css
[data-toggle="buttons"] {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}
[data-toggle="buttons"]::after,
[data-toggle="buttons"]::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-50% - 0.25em);
  font-size: 24px;
  color: blue;
}
[data-toggle="buttons"]::after {
  content: "1";
  left: 0;
}
[data-toggle="buttons"]::before {
  content: "2";
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```